# Backup of the database in entity framework

Tags: asp.net

i working with entity famework i need to transfer that code

```
RESTORE DATABASE [showing8-5-2013] FROM  DISK = N'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\Company.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10
```

to code Entity frame work

any help thanks

Comment: If you not just talk about executing this piece of code, this will not be possible.

Comment: You could also throw your code into an stored-procedure and bind that to EF.

Answer (score 1):

EF is a DB neutral provider concept. Such commands are by their nature DB specific. EF exposes a way to execute an SQL command:

```
MyContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand();
```

But you may as well just do it directly.
Pass your SQL command into a custom routine eg:

```
private static bool ExecuteSqlStatement(string connectionString, string statement) {
        int rowsAffected;
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
            using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(statement, sqlConnection)) {
                try {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    rowsAffected = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    // your handler or re-throw.... 
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return rowsAffected == -1;
        // see  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx
    }
```